# Community User has lost its avatar

Tags: bug, community-user

That must count as a bug!

(Haha thanks, *this question doesn't meet our quality standards*, I hope it meets community's avatar someday, at least)

[image]

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/367454/why-has-communitys-profile-picture-changed

Comment: When someone tries to upvote community, but the rep doesn't change: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KjsSvjA5TuE